# How to implement indoor navigation application using Unity3d on Project Tango?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I'd like to implement indoor navigation application using Unity3d on Project Tango.

Could anyone share me the train of thought about this?

My rough idea shows below:

1. Get the whole build mesh by Tango Constructor
2. Import into Unity3d as .obj
3. Bark whole mesh as Navmesh
4. Name and Mark all interested address or position with ADF together and save with Navmesh
5. Program UI to receive the start/end address and generate the navigation path dynamically.
6. Use AR mark and add on the navigation path floor plane.

Please correct my thoughts and share your experience, I am newbie on Unity3d/Tango.

Comment: If you are new to this, I do not recommend a project this scale. Start with baby steps instead: get familiar with Unity as well as 3D programming in general, c# if you don't know it, OOP if you are not into it yet. Hm. Basically that.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your comments, basic knowledge is Ok for me , and I had implemented serveal tango apps so far. Please kindly give more idea on indoor navigation application.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing what you are doing but without the navmesh and ADF. What you might want to consider is reducing the poly count of the 3D obj using a program like Meshlab. I dont know if they fixed that in the Mira release but previously a 'small' room would yield something like.. 1.2 million triangles which I can only assume would slow down your navmesh quite a bit.

With navmesh, generation navigation should be very easy! so I think 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6 are no problem at all.

however nr 4, I have no idea if it works. This you must explore on your own. Naming/marking an adress using ADF? You are thinking it will recognize itself in the environment and then providing the adress? How will it save it with the navmesh? I am sure you will be able to make it work.

good luck.